# Why is drawPath not working?

Tags: android, draw, android-canvas

I have this code for drawpath and nothing shows up and I cant figure out why.

```
//i move the path's starting point somewhere up here to a point.
//get center x and y are the centers of a picture. it works when i
//do drawline and store the different starting points 
//but i want it to look continuous not like a lot of different
//lines

path.lineTo(a.getCenterX(), a.getCenterY());
path.moveTo(a.getCenterX(), a.getCenterY());


p.setStrokeWidth(50);
p.setColor(Color.BLACK);
canvas.drawPath(path,p);
```

[image: drawpath image]

thanks in advance

Comment: where are you invoking this code?

Comment: in thhe ondraw method. when i loop through the pictures and do drawline it works but it does not look continuous. you can tell that they are seperate lines.

Comment: What do you mean they are separate lines/it is not continuous?  Can you possibly post a screenshot/video or describe this more completely?  Also, make sure you're calling super.onDraw() at the top of your onDraw method.

Comment: i added that. i will upload a screenshot

Answer (score 6, accepted):

i had to add this to paint in order to make it work. dunno why.

```
mPaint.setDither(true);
mPaint.setColor(0xFFFFFF00);
mPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);    
mPaint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);
mPaint.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.ROUND);
mPaint.setStrokeWidth(3);
```

Answer (score 14):

A new Paint instance only *fills* paths.

To **stroke** paths, set the Paint style:

```
paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
```

If the background you're painting on is black, change the color, so you can see the paint:

```
paint.setColor(Color.RED);   // something other than the background color
```

Optional:

```
paint.setStrokeWidth(10);  // makes the line thicker
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer in my opinion, since it also provides explanation as to why one should set something extra on the Paint instance, in order for the path to be drawn.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way to solve your problem is by changing the code as follows:

```
private final int strokeWidth = 50;

path.lineTo(a.getCenterX() + strokewidth / 2, a.getCenterY() + strokeWidth / 2);
path.moveTo(a.getCenterX(), a.getCenterY());

p.setStrokeWidth(strokeWidth);
p.setColor(Color.BLACK);
canvas.drawPath(path,p);
```

You may have to play with this, but this should basically overlap the lines so it looks like they are continuous.

You will likely have to put a switch statement in for which direction you are drawing in, but that should be fairly trivial.

I hope this helps!

Comment: this is what i was thinking about doing but i was thinking drawpath might be a bit more efficient. was i using drawpath correctly?

Comment: You were using it correctly, you just have to remember that it counts the drawpath as the center of the line.  You could play with using different brushes and see if it works better, but for a straight line, I think this is the best fix.  Also, this does not make it any less efficient, this is an extremely lightweight algorithm (adding 2 integers in the arguments).

Comment: it ended up being a problem with the paint. see posted answer.